# React Router change the link but can't changed the body

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

React router Link tag wokred in the first page and page also changed but in the 2nd page have many link If i click on this link it can changed the link but not body how can i fix it...
Router code :

```
            <Switch>
          <Route exact strict path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact strict path="/about/">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route exact strict path="/channel/:title" component={withRouter(Dashboard)} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

**2nd page code**

```
   function Dashboard() {
const { title } = useParams();
return (
   <div>
     <Play 
     title={title}
     />
   </div>
 );
}
```

**Passing some data via props**

```
//this is <Play/> component code just showing here shortly
<Router>
<VideoPlayer
      controls={true}
      src={this.state.link}
      poster={this.state.poster}
      width={window.screen.width}
      height={window.screen.height - (window.screen.width+100)}
    />
  <Link to="/channel/Rtv">Rtv</Link>
      </div>
      </Router>
```

**just showing a little part of this code...**
*please help me ...how can i fix the error*

Full code is here:
https://gist.github.com/fahadali32/8643d33a2328c1375552e4ba7637fc92

Comment: You'll probably need to post a complete example (e.g. a GitHub repo or gist), as the code you show looks just fine. Also check the JavaScript console for error messages which might reveal what's going wrong.

Comment: Ok i will do that please help me...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fahadali32/8643d33a2328c1375552e4ba7637fc92

Comment: Please check this out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i find the answer just simply add

```
<div key={this.props.link}>
<VideoPlayer controls={true} src={this.state.link} poster={this.state.poster} width={window.screen.width} height={window.screen.height - (window.screen.width+100)} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`withRouter`'s documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) mentions:

> `withRouter` does not subscribe to location changes like React Redux’s connect does for state changes. Instead, re-renders after location changes propagate out from the `<Router>` component. This means that `withRouter` does not re-render on route transitions unless its parent component re-renders.

This is not the behavior you want, so you shouldn't use `withRouter`.
So you should replace the line

```js
<Route exact strict path="/channel/:title" component={withRouter(Dashboard)} />
```

with

```js
<Route exact strict path="/channel/:title" component={Dashboard} />
```

If you need to access `match` or `location` or `history`, use the corresponding hook. You're already using `useParams`; you could also use `useLocation` or `useHistory` if you need them.

Comment: Ok done this but same problem ...it can't changed the body...

Comment: Can you try`<Route exact strict path="/channel/:title"><Dashboard/></Route>`?

Comment: Yes but same result

Comment: if u don't mind please make a gist so that i can get the error ...please :)